# Manage Exchange 2007 from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, exchange, remote

Can someone tell me what tools I need to remotely manage Exchange 2007 from a Windows 7 PC? something similar to the remote administration tools used to manage active directory.

If these tools exist, can a link be provided as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the Management console / Management Shell.  Put in the Exchange 2007 installation disk and choose a custom install.  Install only the management Tools.